# How to run Proc COMPARE for data set names listed in Excel file

Tags: sas

Use Case: I have 200+ SAS data sets whose names are in an Excel file. I want to write a SAS script which reads the names of the datasets (2 at a time) from Excel and run a proc compare for them.

I do not want to write 200+ proc compare statements. Is there a way to attain this?

P.S. I am an absolute beginner in SAS

Comment: what are the columns in the excel file ?

Comment: Te excel file contains names of sas extract that are to be matched as columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the excel file has two columns, called Set1 and Set2, and that we want to compare the Set1 in a row with set2 in the same row. I've included a picture of my test data.

[image]

The code below provides a simple solution. Import the list of data sets, write code for the compare steps for each row in the imported list, run the code. You can of course easily add options or modifications to the comapare steps by adding them in the quotes in the put statement. Replace "yourpath" and "yourfile" in the macro call with your actual path and file name.

```
%macro compare (file=);
/*  Import list*/
proc import dbms=xlsx file="&file" out=list replace;
run;

/*  For each line in list, write code for a proc compare step to a temporary text file.*/
filename code temp;

data _null_;
    set list;
    file code;
    put "proc compare data=" set1 " compare=" set2 "; run;";
run;

/*  Run code*/
%include code;  
%mend;
%compare(file=%str(yourpath\yourfile.xlsx))
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to import the data set names data and use a data step that generates the step code and invokes it with `call execute`.

For example:

```
proc import ... out=namesOfDataSets;
...  

data _null_;
  set namesOfDataSets;
  stepcode = 'Proc Compare base=' || dataset1 || ' compare=' || dataset2 || ';';
  call execute (stepcode);

  if _n_ = 3 then stop; * remove this line once you are sure the step code is ok and you want to do all 200 ;
run;
```